# A conjectured q-continued fraction related to the Göllnitz-Gordon partition identities

Tags: nt.number-theory, partitions, continued-fractions

Given $q=e^{2i\pi\tau}$ with $|q|\lt1$, define 
the well-known [Göllnitz-Gordon identities](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Goellnitz-GordonIdentities.html) 
$$A(q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{q^{n(n+1)}(-q;q^2)_n}{(q^2;q^2)_n}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-q^{8n-3})(1-q^{8n-4})(1-q^{8n-5})}, \\ \phantom{a} \\
B(q)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{q^{n^2}(-q;q^2)_n}{(q^2;q^2)_n}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-q^{8n-1})(1-q^{8n-4})(1-q^{8n-7})},$$
as well as the following conjectured $q$-[continued fraction](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction), which is related to the Göllnitz-Gordon identities:

$$H(q)=\cfrac{q^{1/2}(1-q)}{1+q^2-\cfrac{q^2(1+q)(1+q^3)}{1+q^6+\cfrac{q^4(1-q^3)(1-q^5)}{1+q^{10}-\cfrac{q^6(1+q^5)(1+q^7)}{1+q^{14}+\cfrac{q^8(1-q^7)(1-q^9)}{1+q^{18}-\ddots}}}}}$$

One can analogously compare it with the famous 
[Rogers–Ramanujan continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_continued_fraction) which is related to the [Rogers–Ramanujan identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_identities).

***Question:*** How do we show that $$H(q) = \frac{q^{1/2}A(q)}{B(q)}\text{?}$$

Comment: The only q-continued fraction I know of is that which was established by Ramanujan and rediscovered by Göllnitz and Gordon. $$H(q)=\cfrac{q^{1/2}}{1+q+\cfrac{q^2}{1+q^3+\cfrac{q^4}{1+q^5+\ddots}}}$$